# you don't currently have permission to access this folder

Tags: permissions, windows, cygwin, npm

I am trying to building a folder (name:components) within a build folder which contains only html files from the existing component folder using the following code.

`find components -iname "*.html" -exec rsync -R {} ./build/ ';'`

[image: Building component folder]

And it's running perfectly the component is building within build folder but when i access the component folder I'll get following error.

[image: Error Occurring]

I'm looking for the permanent solution so that i wouldn't have to give the permission again and again to the folder for accessing.

What i can add into the given code so that automatically authentication give to the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many `rsync` options whose purpose is to preserve attributes of copied files/dirs. Assuming that your source files have the permissions you want use the flag for preserving permissions: `--perms` (or `-p`).

If the source files don't have the permissions you need then you can use the `--chmod` flag to set permissions of the target files/dirs to whatever you want. For this to work you also need to specify `--perms`. The chmod flag takes arguments similar to the `chmod(1)` command but extends them so you can specify permissions only for directories or only for files. For example this would give write permission to the owner for files only: `rsync --perms --chmod Fu+w`. It looks like you may not have execute permissions on your directories (at the least) so you could try `--chmod D+x` for starters.

(I'm assuming that the owner is properly set for your copied files. If not then there is also a `--chown=USER:GROUP` flag available.)

Note: I'm working with the limited amount of information you've supplied. If you aren't able to figure things out from the above then please run `ls -la` against one of the target directories and post the result in your question.