# Apache doesn't have permission to access the vbox share folder in Ubuntu 18

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-httpd, virtualbox, shared-folders

I have mounted a share folder (sf_test) to use as my apache root directory:

```
drwxrwx---  1 root vboxsf    0 Dec 28 23:42 sf_test
```

I have added my user to the vboxsf group and I can cd in there and make change.
also I have added my apache user (www-data) to the vboxsf group so that I can access it via http requets. Unfortunately when I try to browse the web page it gives a 403 error (for permission denied)

here is the vboxsf group users

```
vboxsf:x:999:myuser,www-data,root
```

here is my apache users :

```
root      1054  0.0  1.7 422844 35628 ?        Ss   Dec28   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1057  0.0  0.5 422932 11580 ?        S    Dec28   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1058  0.0  0.5 422932 11580 ?        S    Dec28   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1059  0.0  0.5 422932 11580 ?        S    Dec28   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1060  0.0  0.5 422932 11580 ?        S    Dec28   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1061  0.0  0.5 422932 11580 ?        S    Dec28   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1064  0.0  0.5 422932 11580 ?        S    Dec28   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
eramba    1226  0.0  0.0  14224  1028 pts/0    S+   01:06   0:00 grep -E --color=auto (apache|httpd)
```

I have checked similar questions like
[Apache can't access file while is has permission](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/262138/apache-cant-access-file-while-is-has-permission)
or
[you don't currently have permission to access this folder](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/388757/you-dont-currently-have-permission-to-access-this-folder)
but they weren't useful.

I wonder what I can do change the permissions of the shared folder.

Comment: Can you add the respective snippets from the error & access log?

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange.  It would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts.  This will interfere with commenting, editing your own posts, and accepting an answer.  You should use the [contact form](/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, these are https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/328940/mohamadreza and https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/328959/user328959.  You’ll then be able to accept your answer, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution
I should have added "require all grant" to the apache config file

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange.  It would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts.  This will interfere with commenting, editing your own posts, and accepting an answer.  You should use the [contact form](/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, these are https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/328940/mohamadreza and https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/328959/user328959.  You’ll then be able to accept your answer, etc.